# Espresso in Android Studio and NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I'm using Double Espresso from Jake Wharton, which helps with Google Espresso integration in Android Studio and Gradle. The trouble comes with compatibility library (support-v4), which classes are unavailable in test builds:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:238)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:167)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1840)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:262)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:184)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:379)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:114)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5142)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.skoumal.project.activity.MainActivity
at net.skoumal.project.test.MainActivityTest.<init>(MainActivityTest.java:30)
... 19 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple, just change this lines in your gradle.build:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'
androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3')
```

by adding exlude for compatibility library:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'
androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```